# Least Squares Problem with Generalized Tikhonov Regularization

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-optimization, least-squares

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu > 0$. Find the matrix $A$ and vector $b$ to solve this problem using the least squares approximation:

$$\min \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x -c\|_{2}^2 + \mu \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1} (x_{i+1} - x_{i})^2 \right\}$$

Comment: This is the first version of the problem. I will be updating it with ideas. Is there some way to draft a question?

Comment: you can edit your post using the 'edit' button on the bottom left, to revise your question and update the viewers on your progress.

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\displaystyle||x-c||$ to $\displaystyle\|x-c\|$, and did some other MathJax code improvements.  Next, maybe I'll think about the question.

Comment: Usually in a least-squares problem one would say that $x$ is constrained to lie in some specified subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.  This is different.

Comment: Is it given that $\mu>0$?

Comment: yes, $\mu > 0$.

Comment: In effect you've got a sum of two norms, but with one of them centered at $c$, and one of them involving a singular matrix.  It's singular because the vector whose components are $x_{i+1}-x_i$ is constrained to lie in the space in which the sum of all components is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be generalized as following (Practically,  Tikhonov Regularization of Least Squares):

$$ \arg \min_{x} f \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{x} \left\| A x - c \right\|_{2}^{2} + \mu \left\| D x \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

Where in you case $ A = I $ and $ D $ is the derivative matrix.

The above is Convex and Smooth hence the solution, $ \hat{x} $, is given by the stationary point:

$$ \nabla f \left( \hat{x} \right) = 2 {A}^{T} \left( A x - c \right) + 2 \mu {D}^{T} D x = 0 \Rightarrow \hat{x} = \left( {A}^{T} A + \mu {D}^{T} D \right)^{-1} {A}^{T} c $$

Setting your data ($ A = I $) yields:

$$ \hat{x} = \left( I + \mu {D}^{T} D \right)^{-1} c $$